# Export SQL Server 2014 database (2008 compatible) in a backup file compatible with 2012

Tags: sql-server

I'm a bit stuck with this scenario. My dev VM has SQL Server 2014 on it, and I've been working on a SQL Server 2008 database. The 2008 database is listed as '2008 compatible'. I now need to put this on a demo server which has an older edition of SQL Server (2012), and I find that 2008 compatible DBs don't create 2008 compatible backups (which I would have thought would be a given).

I'm actually trying to backup from SQL 2014 and recover into SQL Server 2012. How do I get a SQL Server 2008 or SQL Server 2012 compatible backup file from my 2008 compatible database?

Thanks.

Comment: Simple. You don't. Database backups are backwards compatible but not forward compatible. Meaning that you can restore a backup from an older version. An older version cannot restore a database from a newer version. And just changing the compatibility mode does not make the backup suddenly work in an older version. You would have to script the ddl and data.

Comment: If you want to go from a newer version (2014) of SQL Server back to an older one (2008 or 2012), there is **no way, no hack, no tool, no trick, no black voodoo magic** to do this using backup/restore or detach/attach. This just will **NEVER** work - period. If you need to "go back", the only option is to generate change scripts from your 2014 machine, and run those on the older instances.

Comment: Also beware that features matter too here. i.e. if you backup a enterprise edition, you'll need to restore to an enterprise edition for those enterprise features to work.

Comment: The database compatibility level that you're probably talking about ("2008 compatible database") is **only** for ensuring that the T-SQL feature and behavior match the compatible version - this compatibility level has **nothing to do** with the internal structures of the `.mdf` or `.bak` file - fiddling with the compatibility level does **NOT** help you with "going back" to an older version of SQL Server

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to script the SQL database creation, in SQL Server Management Studio :

> right click on the DB -> Task -> Generate script

From there a series off dialog to choose what to generate with the SQL command creation and where, in clipboard or file (recommanded for big DB), with optionally the data as some Insert Into SQL command. To find the data option click on the "Advanced" button and search for "Type of data to script"

Comment: And note that it's often better to execute the generated script SQL file with SQLCMD as it's sometime too big for Management Studio